# Trouble implementing directx IMFmediaEngineProtectedContent for metro app

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro, directx, ms-media-foundation

I am implementing `IMFmediaEngineProtectedContent` interface for metro app (**win store app**), and have become confused while trying to implement this function:

```
HRESULT SetOPMWindow(
  [in]  HWND hwnd
);
```

As far as I understand, `HWND` belongs to win **MFC**, but I need to use this for metro window (CoreWindow).
[IMF API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that it supports Windows Store apps.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

HWND isn´t MFC specific, its just the handle of your window.
[This site](http://kennykerr.ca/2012/11/09/windows-8-whered-you-put-my-hwnd/) has a nice documentation on how to get the handle for windows store apps.

Using this information you can query the handle from your CoreWindow.

Comment: thanks Joachim, is this the correct procedure to retrieve a HWND ? (as Microsoft intended ) seems kind of a workaround.

Comment: well, imho it IS some kind of workaround. i guess microsoft does not want devs to get in contact with HWND´s and stuff anymore, therefore hide it as much as they can.